# Can i disable skin loading for YUI3 modules?

Tags: javascript, css, skin, yui3

I am using a YUI3 module called "panel" which comes up with a dependency to some css files for skinning. These files are always loaded if the module is required. Every time i'm using the panel i have a custom css and don't need the skin.

So my question: Is there a way to disable the css skin loading for one or all YUI3 modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a boolean switch for this:

```
YUI_config.fetchCSS = false;
```